# chain up multiple IFs - evaluate next only if current is false

Tags: c#

I have a method that checks multiple conditions to execute further, only to proceed to next if the current condition evaluates to false, otherwise the method will exit without evaluating further conditions. And the number of conditions vary in different implementations (subclasses).

I'm limited by my creativity to make it look any better than using the dreaded goto statement. Is there any better way to do the following:

```
    public bool DoSomething()
    {
        bool result = true;

        if (exclusion1)
        {
            result = false; goto Exit_Now;
        }
        if (exclusion2)
        {
            result = false; goto Exit_Now;
        }
        if (exclusion3)
        {
            result = false; goto Exit_Now;
        }
        if (exclusion4)
        {
            result = false; goto Exit_Now;
        }
        if (exclusion5)
        {
            result = false; goto Exit_Now;
        }

        if (result)
        {
            //do something
        }

    Exit_Now:
        return result;
    }
```

EDIT: In response to the answers, I understand using "else if" and conditional OR '||' operator are the obvious choices:

Subquery: which is more performant? I ask because this happens inside a loop and each evaluation takes about 30-40 ms. What is supposed to be finished in under a minute is taking up to two minutes without the goto statements in the code given above. Hence, the query. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Use else if instead of multiple ifs

Comment: As the exclusions do the same operation, you can use [Conditional logical OR operator ||](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-or-operator-).

Comment: `Subquery: which is more performant?` https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: You may want to experiment with ordering the checks: first the fastest checks, or first the checks that exclude the most (so you can skip the other checks). Of course this depends on your exact situation

Comment: Thanks @Jawad for the simplest yet effective solution. I could not think clearly because I could not visualize this since the actual code is not as simple as the sample presented above, which should be in the first place. I'll look into making it simpler.

Comment: Thanks @Hans Kesting for the suggestion. That should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can fit your exclusion tests into the if statement, just use `else if` statements;

```cs
        if (exclusion1)
        {
            result = false;
        }
        else if (exclusion2)
        // etc ...
        else if (result)
        {
            //do something
        }
```

But I find it's much simpler, and easier to read, to just return early;

```cs
        if (exclusion1)
            return false;
```

Answer (score 4):

One way to simplify this is to treat the exclusions as a [guard clause](https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html):

```
public bool DoSomething() 
{ 
    if (exclusion1 || 
        exclusion2 || 
        exclusion3 || 
        exclusion4 || 
        exclusion5) 
    { 
        return false;
    } 

    //do something
    return true; 
}
```

This also has the benefit of removing the nesting of the `//do something` towards the end.

Answer (score 2):

you can always do this:

`result = !(exclusion || exclustion2 ...|| exclusionN);`